# Getting Service Unavailable when setting up domain name

Tags: entries, deployment

Currently I'm trying to push my deployed website to the actual domain name it needs to be under using DigitalOcean. The website works perfectly when accessing it directly from the droplets ip address.

I've set the name servers on GoDaddy to be Digital Ocean's, but when trying to access the Craft site at the domain name URL it throws a craft error saying

> "Service Unavailable,Our site is temporarily unavailable. Please try
>   again later."

Is there something I need to do in Craft to make sure it knows about the domain name change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this document: https://craftcms.com/docs/multi-environment-configs

You can configure it differently for local, staging, production, etc, by the name of the domain name